# Executing JavaScript on an iframe's contents from a different domain

Tags: javascript, security, browser-bugs

Is this denied by the browser? Is it possible?

If so, are that browser bugs that allow it to happen? I noticed this:

http://html5sec.org

How can you close these bugs and prevent them from working on your website? Can I detect if someone is trying to execute javascript from another domain?

Thanks.

Comment: If you for example include google ads or fb widgets or anything in your website this means you trust him ... is on you to don't include this code and if you try to stop the code it will not show ads for example then which is the point?

Comment: I don't mean including others JS, I mean they can create their own website and load mine in an iframe, then manipulate it with JS.

Comment: ... i found a solution about this but i dont know if works with all browsers
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header
 but if you showing your ads in their websites better add it as a term or condition in the contract ... i didn't find any other solution about this

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is executed by the browser, not the server. If a user wanted to, they can execute javascript on a website without an iframe. (Type `javascript:alert('hello');` in the address bar).

You can not stop this, because it is being executed on the client, not on your site itself. Design your site in a way that no matter what they do with javascript, it can not affect the integrity of your site. Use server-side authentication and sessions, **sanitize your database input**, and do not do any security-based operations on the client side.

Comment: But with button actions like javascript onClick event, they can be invoked via javascript. Is it possible? Could someone load an iframe with my site in it and invoke an onClick event? No matter what I do, that's a security risk.

Comment: Yes, it is trivial. `document.getElementById('myButton').click()`

Comment: Not if it's in an iframe you can't do that.

Comment: This should work: `$(document).ready(function() {
            var frame = $('#iframeID').get(0).contentDocument;
            $('#childBtn', frame).click()

        });`

Comment: Actually, no that doesn't work cross-domain. But I still don't see why manipulating it in an iframe is any more/less of a security risk than going to your site direct and manipulating it.

Comment: An in an HTA you could manipulate anything you want in an iFrame